# Change state of clicked button inside StreamBuilder list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, button, state, stream-builder

I have a StreamBuilder which returns me a ListView of items.

For each item I also have ElevatedButton button.

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      pressGeoON = !pressGeoON;
      if (pressGeoON == true) {
        favoriteDataList.add(snapshot
            .data?.docs[index].id);
      } else {
        favoriteDataList.removeWhere(
            (item) =>
                item ==
                snapshot.data
                    ?.docs[index].id);
      }
    });
  },
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor:
        MaterialStateProperty.all<
            Color>(
      Colors.deepPurple,
    ),
  ),
  child: Icon(
    Icons.favorite,
    color: pressGeoON
        ? Colors.blue
        : Colors.red,
  ),
)
```

I'm trying to change state of only clicked button, but so far with my code it always changes state of all buttons inside of list.
How can I change state only of clicked button and not all of them?

Comment: this is because you have only one `pressGeoON` that controls all the items (`color: pressGeoON? Colors.blue : Colors.red,`)

Comment: Yes, I also found some similar questions and possible solutions with for loops, but honestly I have no ideas how it may work with for loop. I would be glad for any code example suggestions.

Comment: basically you need a list/map/set of `bool`s where each entry would control one specific `ListView` item

Comment: @pskink Thank you for this hint! I found out a solution :)

Comment: sure, your welcome :-)

Comment: Would be great for the future people if you share your answer in here